# Strange behavior with "let" inside a named function

Tags: elisp

Consider the following MWE:

```
(setq a-cat 'derpy)

(let ((cats '(fluffy derpy)))
  (while cats
    (print cats)
    (setq cats (delq a-cat cats))
    (print cats)
    (print (pop cats))))
```

The result looks like this:

```
(fluffy derpy) ; original local binding of "cats".
(fluffy)       ; "cats" after the removal of 'derpy ("a-cat").
fluffy         ; the first and only element left in "cats" (with pop).
nil            ; empty "cats" after pop. the loop is over.
```

If i evaluate the expression several times the result is always the same. But if i wrap it inside a function definition something odd happens:

```
(setq a-cat 'derpy)

(defun cats-test ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((cats '(fluffy derpy)))
    (while cats
      (print cats)
      (setq cats (delq a-cat cats))
      (print cats)
      (print (pop cats)))))

(cats-test)
```

First result (as expected):

```
(fluffy derpy)
(fluffy)
fluffy
nil
```

Second and subsequent results:

```
(fluffy) ; "cats" local binding with only 1 element!??
(fluffy) ; "a-cat" wasn't found.
fluffy   ; (pop cats).
nil      ; end of loop.
```

If i'm not mistaken, since "cats" isn't a global variable it's value should remain untouched after calling the function.

If i store the expression inside an anonymous function (with `(lambda ())`) and call it (with `funcall`), the result is the same as evaluating the expression alone, i.e. no weird list modification.

<strike>What exactly is going on here?</strike>

Edit:

This prevents the list from being modified after subsequent calls of the "cats-test" function:

```
(defun cats-test ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((cats (list 'fluffy 'derpy)))
    (while cats
      ...
```

Now each time the function is called the original value of the "cats" local variable is (re)defined through the `list` function.

Comment: self-modifying code alert!

Comment: @sds Ok, now i see it clearly! The function is indeed modifying itself. Should've read your previous answer thoroughly before posting. Thanks!